# Firefox says "unprotected" but tcpdump does not show PW

Tags: password-encryption, tcpdump

When i login to a certain http-website firefox warns against insecure connection.

Than i perform a login while reading the traffic over tcpdump. Theoreticaly i should see my PW as plain text or a hash of it. But it is not there!

Can anyone help me if the PW is really being broadcasted unencrypted on the net?
How to go on testing it?

Thx a lot...

Comment: just to be clear, the login page is always showing a simple http protocoll

Comment: The firefox warning just means they aren't using SSL to protect traffic back to the server. That said, any data entered into forms could be processed by javascript before sending back to the server. Can you view the page source and see if there is any javascript?

Comment: Yes it is. Here some passages:

Comment: Yes it is. Here some passages: `<!--if (document.formlogin.username && document.formlogin.password){if(document.formlogin.username.value!="") document.formlogin.password.focus();}`. I am not the javascript guy. Is some encryption going on before i send the login data to the server?

Comment: "<!--" is the start of an html comment so all the code inside of it isn't executed. Is there any "<script>" tags?

Comment: Yes, there are some linked scripts. Look:                `</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Services/Form/js/Form.js?vers=5-0-22-2017-05-17"></script>`    There are a few such linked javascripts, they just do not fit here in the comment. The question is, can they encrypt the data even if SSL is not used?